# Number of combination with repetitions containing a subset of all the root element

Tags: combinatorics, multisets

I am in trouble with this question: Given the set $S$={$a,b,c,d,e,f$} and 10 position to arrange these elements. How many combination with repetitions exist if the only allowed must contain at least one of each elements of $S$?

For example a valid configuration can be {$a,a,b,b,c,d,e,f,f,f$} and
an incorrect one can be {$a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b$} .

I try to find a solution that can be applicable to a Set of size $m$, with $n$ position to arrange the elements and with $n$>$m$.
My starting assumption is that if I consider the Diophantine equation each unknown of solving equation (fulfilling the request) must have at least $1$ like result. However this does not help me to calculate the number of equations that fulfill the initial question. There is an easy or a tricky way to solve this problem?

Comment: Just to get this straight, you want the number of combinations of 10 items of 5 types where you must include at least one of each type. 
It that a complete description of the problem?

Comment: its rather self contradicting:in the first line you say there are 10 postions to **arrange** and in the second line you use the word **combinations**!You understand they are different dont you?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I want the number of combination of 10 items of 5 types that must include at least one of each type. Obviously, because the items are more than types the combination are with repetitions.

Comment: If the order matters, then this is not a combinations with repetition problem.  If the order does not matter, you should not use the word arrange.

Comment: The problem mentions **6** types, not **5**, and I have answered accordingly. idk how **5** has crept into some comments !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have heard of a counting technique called *stars and bars* which gives that the number of ways of placing $n$ identical objects into $k$ distinct bins = $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$

Possibly what is bothering you is that here the "objects" are distinct numerals. Then just imagine that the *bins* are numbered $1$ through $6$ and unnumbered identical objects magically acquire the numeral of the bin they are put in, then it fits the stars and bars format.

Firstly put $1$ object in each bin, $4$ are left to be put, and by stars and bars, # of ways = $\binom{4+6-1}{6-1}$